# Python - Dijkstra's algorithm in O(V+ElogV) time complexity

Tags: python, dijkstra

I would like to implement the above mentioned algorithm in Python. Time Complexity of Dijkstra's Algorithm is O(V2), but I would like to implement it using min-priority queue so it drops down to O(V+ElogV).

*Heres an example input:*

The program should 2 problems, src: 0 dest: 2 and src: 1 dest: 2. 3 vertexes will be provided by the input and there will be 3 edges provided also, all of these are separated by an empty line.

```
2
3
3

0   2
1   2

2   0
-4  1
6   3

1   0
1   2
0   2
```

*Solution:*

```
5.0     10.2
```

*Heres my current code:*

```
import math
import sys
 
def build_graph(edges, weights, e):
    graph = edges

    for i in range(e):
        graph[i].append(weights[i])
        
    return graph

def debug():
    print(pontparok)
    print(csucsok)
    print(utszakaszok)
    print(hosszak)

def read(n, bemenet):
    for i in range(n):
        temp = input().split("\t")
        bemenet[i] = temp
        bemenet[i][0] = int(bemenet[i][0])
        bemenet[i][1] = int(bemenet[i][1])

def dijkstra(edges, src, dest, n):
    dist = [0] * n
    current = src

    for i in range(n):
        dist[i] = sys.maxsize
    dist[src] = 0

    explored = [False] * n

    q = 0
    while not explored[dest] and q < 1000:
        q += 1
        min = sys.maxsize
        minVertex = current
        for edge in edges:
            if edge[0] == current and not explored[edge[1]]:
                if min > dist[edge[1]]:
                    min = dist[edge[1]]
                    minVertex = edge[1]
            elif edge[1] == current and not explored[edge[0]]:
                if min > dist[edge[0]]:
                    min = dist[edge[0]]
                    minVertex = edge[0]
        
        current = minVertex
        explored[current] = True
        for edge in edges:
            if edge[0] == current:
                if dist[current] + edge[2] < dist[edge[1]]:
                    dist[edge[1]] = dist[current] + edge[2]
            elif edge[1] == current:
                if dist[current] + edge[2] < dist[edge[0]]:
                    dist[edge[0]] = dist[current] + edge[2] 
    
    return round(dist[dest], 2)

p = int(input())
n = int(input())
e = int(input())
input()

pontparok = [[0] * 2] * p
csucsok = [[0] * 2] * n
utszakaszok = [[0] * 2] * e
hosszak = [0] * e

read(p, pontparok)
input()
read(n, csucsok)
input()
read(e, utszakaszok)

for i in range(e):
    hosszak[i] = math.sqrt(pow((csucsok[utszakaszok[i][0]][0] - csucsok[utszakaszok[i][1]][0]), 2) + pow((csucsok[utszakaszok[i][0]][1] - csucsok[utszakaszok[i][1]][1]), 2))

#debug()

graph = build_graph(utszakaszok, hosszak, e)
#print(hosszak)

for i in range(p):
    if i == p - 1:
        print(dijkstra(graph, pontparok[i][0], pontparok[i][1], n))
    else:
        print(dijkstra(graph, pontparok[i][0], pontparok[i][1], n), end="\t")
```

Comment: Are you asking how to input numbers? When I use that input, it is spaces, not a tab.

Comment: No, no! I would like to fix Dijkstra’s alogrithm. Its not working correctly.

Comment: It doesn't run immediately using copy/paste due to the tabs being changed to spaces on this website. From the way you posed the question, I assumed this was the working quadratic implementation. I thought you just needed help using heapq.

Comment: note that python's heapq doesn't directly support changing the priority of an item, which we need. This is addressed with a suggested solution (just mark the old value with an ignore flag, and add the new value normally) in https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I cannot see a question. Please, formulate a question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import heapq
import math

def read(n, bemenet):
    for i in range(n):
        temp = input().split("\t")
        bemenet[i] = temp
        bemenet[i][0] = int(bemenet[i][0])
        bemenet[i][1] = int(bemenet[i][1])


def dijkstra(graph, starting_vertex, destination_vertex):
    distances = {vertex: float('infinity') for vertex in graph}
    distances[starting_vertex] = 0

    pq = [(0, starting_vertex)]
    while len(pq) > 0:
        current_distance, current_vertex = heapq.heappop(pq)

        for neighbor, weight in graph[current_vertex].items():
            distance = current_distance + weight

            if distance < distances[neighbor]:
                distances[neighbor] = distance
                heapq.heappush(pq, (distance, neighbor))

    return round(distances[destination_vertex], 2)

def build_graph(edges, weights, e):
    graph = edges

    for i in range(e):
        graph[i].append(weights[i])
        
    return graph


p = int(input())
n = int(input())
e = int(input())
input()

pontparok = [[0] * 2] * p
csucsok = [[0] * 2] * n
utszakaszok = [[0] * 2] * e
hosszak = [0] * e

read(p, pontparok)
input()
read(n, csucsok)
input()
read(e, utszakaszok)

for i in range(e):
    hosszak[i] = math.sqrt(pow((csucsok[utszakaszok[i][0]][0] - csucsok[utszakaszok[i][1]][0]), 2) + pow((csucsok[utszakaszok[i][0]][1] - csucsok[utszakaszok[i][1]][1]), 2))

graph2 = build_graph(utszakaszok, hosszak, e)
graph = { }
[graph.setdefault(i, []) for i in range(n)] 
for i in range(n):
    graph[i] = {}
for edge in graph2:
    graph[edge[0]].update({edge[1]: edge[2]})
    graph[edge[1]].update({edge[0]: edge[2]})

for i in range(p):
    if i == p - 1:
        print(dijkstra(graph, pontparok[i][0], pontparok[i][1]))
    else:
        print(dijkstra(graph, pontparok[i][0], pontparok[i][1]), end="\t")
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Maybe you can add some changes you made or "Here is the updated code."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).